# Using JSON Decoder to read json file

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have an app that gets weather JSON data in the following format:

```
{
   "coord":{
      "lon":-1.74,
      "lat":60.5
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":801,
         "main":"Clouds",
         "description":"few clouds",
         "icon":"02n"
      }
   ],
   "main":{
      "temp":285.17,
      "feels_like":275.99,
      "temp_min":285.17,
      "temp_max":285.17
   },
   "timezone":3600,
   "id":2654970,
   "name":"Brae",
   "cod":200
}
```

I have set up Codable structures as follows:

```
struct weatherApi: Codable {
    
    var name:String = ""
    var base:String = ""
    var weather:[weatherApiWeather]
}

struct weatherApiWeather: Codable {
    var description: String = ""
}
```

The code used to get the JSON data is as follows:

```
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
    
    if error == nil && data != nil {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
            let currentWeather = try decoder.decode(weatherApi.self, from: data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                self.lblCurrentWeather.text = currentWeather.weather.description //UILabel
            }
        }
        catch {
            print ("Error parsing Json")
        }

    }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

This gets the data but I have  2 questions:

1 - I am decoding the data for the weather description but when displaying it in the label self.currentWeather.text it displays

```
 [appName.weatherApiWeather(description: "few clouds")]
```

and not just the description. How do I get around this?

2 - I can't seem to access the data held in the JSON file key 'main'. How do I set up the 'weatherApi' key in a structure to get the 'main' data? If I use:

```
struct weatherApi: Codable {
    var name:String = ""
    var base:String = ""
    var weather:[weatherApiMain]
}

struct weatherApiMain: Codable {
   var temp: Double
}
```

I get an error.

Comment: “I get an error” - what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first question -**
Since weather is an array this line is asking for a description of the array, it seems:

```
self.lblCurrentWeather.text = currentWeather.weather.description
```

To get the description, the specific element within the array should be identified, as in this line:

```
self.lblCurrentWeather.text = currentWeather.weather[0].description
```

**For the second question -**

There is more than one main in the JSON above so I wasn't sure which one you needed. For the first one, the access would be like above:

```
anotherLabel.text = currentWeather.weather[0].main
```

For the other main, the model needs to be updated:

```
struct weatherApi: Codable {
    let main:Main
    var name:String = ""
    var base:String = ""
    var weather:[weatherApiMain]
}

struct Main: Codable {
   let temp: Double
}
```

Then accessing the content of main is like this:

```
yetAnotherLabel.text = currentWeather.main.temp
```

Also, each property of the model can be assigned as let rather than var.

Comment: Thanks - did the trick

Answer (score 1):

> I am decoding the data for the weather description but when displaying it in the label `self.currentWeather.text` it displays `[appName.weatherApiWeather(description: "few clouds")]`
> and not just the description.

This is because you are displaying the description of the array:

```
// currentWeather.weather is an array!
self.lblCurrentWeather.text = currentWeather.weather.description
```

You should instead access the description of a desired element of the array. For example, the first one:

```
self.lblCurrentWeather.text = currentWeather.weather.first?.description ?? "No Weather!"
```

I don't know enough about this API to tell you why the weather data is in an array. That you'd have to read the API docs to find out.

> How do I set up the 'weatherApi' key in a structure to get the 'main' data?

You should name the property `main` rather than `weather`:

```
struct weatherApi: Codable {
    var name:String = ""
    var base:String = ""
    var main:[weatherApiMain] // notice the change in the name here!
}
```

The auto-generated `Codable` implemented will use the property names as the JSON keys. You can still use `weather` if you want, but then you'd have to add a `CodingKeys` enum:

```
struct weatherApi: Codable {
    var name:String = ""
    var base:String = ""
    var weather:[weatherApiMain]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case base = "base"
        case weather = "main"
    }
}
```